# How to get Google to display the published date of blog post in the search results?

Tags: google-search, search-results, structured-data, dates

I'd like to display the published date of the posting that I made in the Google search results?

Example:

[image: published date]

I optimized the structured data of my blog last month, the `datePublished` and `dateModified` seems no error, here is the screenshot:

[image: Structured data testing results]

But, the published date still hasn't shown up in the Google search result.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Rich snipped property  "datePublished" in the HTML template of your articles

*Example:*

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-05T08:00:00+08:00"/>
<meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2015-02-05T09:20:00+08:00"/>
```

Please find the folling Documentation
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles#amp-logo-guidelines

If you have changed your page, it will take some time to take effect on google search. However if it starts to show on search results, you will have it instantly for every new post you have

Answer (score 1):

Google should recognize the date automatically. Your posts look pretty new, so perhaps it takes some time. When I google a search for frostali.blogspot.co.id it says "6 days ago".

Answer (score 0):

Just a kind warning, I don't think you want to add dates/time to your google results. It hurts your SEO ranking, as explained in this brilliant article:

https://www.shoutmeloud.com/effect-of-showing-date-stamp-on-blog-traffic-case-study.html

Comment: Dates on newer content will do better, dates on older content will make it do worse. Of course, new and old are relative to the niche.